# Error while adding protobuf dependency to maven

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

I am trying to add protobuf dependency to my maven project.
I have installed the protobuf jar file using 
    mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar\
                           -DgeneratePom=true\
                           -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf\
                           -DartifactId=protobuf-java\
                           -Dfile=protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar\
                           -Dversion=2.5.0

Mypom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ProtobufExample</groupId>
<artifactId>ProtobufTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProtobufTest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skip.tests>false</skip.tests>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>ProtobufTest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/proto/</protoSourceRoot>
                        <includes>
                            <param>**/*.proto</param>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

When I try to test it using "mvn test", I get the following error:
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0 
No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml

Please help me to figure out where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is located based on the following snippet of your pom file:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/
```

The problem is that **protobuf-java** is **not** a plugin. So this couldn't be workgin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the error was with the above snippet of my pom file.